# Distribution of red balls in a picking without replacements

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Suppose that there is a urn with $n$ balls, $pn$ red balls and $(1-p)n$ green balls, where $0< p < 1$.

I pick from this urn balls in a sequential order, uniformly without replacement. For $1 \leq  k \leq n$, let $R_k$ be the total number of red balls I have at the $k$'th step. I am interested in the distribution of $R_k$, for every $k$.

**My attempt**. First, we know that $\Pr[R_1=1] = p$, and that $\Pr[R_n = pn] = 1$. We also know that $$\Pr[R_{k+1} = R_k+1 | R_k] = \frac{pn - R_k}{n-k},$$
since there are $pn-R_k$ red balls left out of $n-k$ (if this value is below $0$ (or above $1$), I assume it is $0$ (or $1$)).
Thus, for some value $m$,
$$\Pr[R_{k+1} = m] = \Pr[R_{k+1} = R_{k}+1 | R_{k} = m-1]\times \Pr[R_{k} = m-1] \\
 + \Pr[R_{k+1} = R_{k} | R_{k} = m]\times \Pr[R_{k} = m], $$

which continues in a recursive manner. I am not sure how to extract from this recursion a closed formula of the distribution of $R_k$, or if it even possible.

Comment: The distribution of $R_k$ is hypergeometric. You can find it without any form of recursion. Picking $k$ balls one by one in a specific order does not differ from picking $k$ balls simultaneously if at stake is the distribution of $R_k$ (and not of random vector $(R_1,\dots,R_k)$).

Comment: thanks, I'll accept that as an answer

Comment: You are welcome. I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution of $R_k$ is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) and can be found directly without any appeal to recursion.

Picking $k$ balls one by one in a specific order does not essentially differ from picking $k$ balls simultaneously if at stake is the finding of the distribution of $R_k$.

Recursion might come in sight if you are after the distribution of random vector $(R_1,…,R_k)$.